# Angular TypeError: Cannot read property 'color' of undefined trying to read data

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am trying to read some data from a locally stored file in Angular 4.

Here is the same data:

```
  {
    "color": "blue"
  }
```

and here is the code from the component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  data;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.http.get('../../assets/data.json')
      .subscribe(res => this.data = res.json());

    console.log(this.data.color);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I keep getting this error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'color' of undefined

What I'm I doing wrong here / How can I fix it?

Comment: You are getting data with 'color' property via a subscribe. At the time when constructor is call, data is still undefined.

Comment: So how to I get the data into my data variable?

Comment: This could help :) https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-request-for-json-data

Comment: No, still getting Undefined

Comment: Where do you check it? at the same place with console.log()? or is it in the view? Have you made changes to put in the ngOnInit?

Comment: I check in the same place

Comment: And you moved it inside the subscribe as the answer suggested? Put console.log(this.data) also please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154088/discussion-between-vega-and-max2020).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the console.log inside the **`subscribe`**

```
this.http.get('../../assets/data.json')
  .subscribe(res => {
     this.data = res.json();
     console.log(this.data.color);
  }
)
```

Comment: Getting an error: component.ts (15,47): ')' expected.

Comment: .subscribe(res => { this.data = res.json(); console.log(this.data.color); });